# getting no mail in the recipient's email address

Tags: java, android, android-studio, smtp

I'm trying to send email directly from my app's ContactUsActivity. The postExecute function also works. It shows the toast "sent". But I'm getting no mail in the recipient's email address.
I provided the recipient's email address as String and the sender's email id I'm getting from firebase. I used Phone authentication in this app.

The stacktrace is pointing at, Transport.send(mimeMessage);

```
// session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){ 
// protected PhoneAuthProvider getPhoneAuthCredential(){ 
// return new PhoneAuthProvider(); 
// } 
// });
```

I didn't use the session but added it in mimeMessage. May be there's the problem. Can you please help me with how to get the Phoneauth protection here instead email and password.

```
public class ContactUsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String message;
    String emailResult;
    String toMail;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);
        
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Button sendMail = findViewById(R.id.sendMail);
        EditText messageText = findViewById(R.id.message);
        message = messageText.getText().toString();

        toMail = "sibamboss98@gmail.com";
        
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        sendMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fStore.collection("users").document(Objects.requireNonNull(user.getPhoneNumber()))
                        .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            emailResult = task.getResult().getString("email");
                            executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    Properties properties = new Properties();

                                    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                                    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                                    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                                    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
                                    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                                    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
                                    try {
                                        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailResult));
                                        mimeMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, String.valueOf(new InternetAddress(toMail)));
                                        mimeMessage.setText(message);
                                        Transport.send(mimeMessage);
                                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(ContactUsActivity.this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(ContactUsActivity.this, "Error getting from email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }
}
```

That's what stacktrace says,

```
2021-07-29 18:12:16.808 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:   nested exception is:
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 25) from /:: (port 55922): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.ContactUsActivity$1$1$1.run(ContactUsActivity.java:104)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.811 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 25) from /:: (port 55922): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:143)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:631)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:571)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.812 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:    ... 10 more
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:136)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:157)
2021-07-29 18:12:16.813 10376-10648/com.luteraa.luteraaesports W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
```

Kindly check the code and let me know where I'm going wrong or I should use any other method.

Comment: Are any exceptions being logged?

Comment: have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: Do you realize that `messageText.setText(emailResult); Toast.makeText(this, toMail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` probably gets executed before the attempt to send the email has finished.  If you want to find out what `emailResult` is, you should use a logger to log it.  Likewise, `e.printStackTrace();` should be a logger call.

Comment: Added the stacktrace.

Comment: That's where it's pointing at,      Transport.send(mimeMessage);

Comment: I didn't use the session but added it in mimeMessage. May be there's the problem. Can you please help me with how to get the Phoneauth protection here instead email and password.

Comment: //                                    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
//                                        protected PhoneAuthProvider getPhoneAuthCredential(){
//                                            return new PhoneAuthProvider();
//                                        }
//                                    });